# Combinatorial problem that a friend asked with some interesting stipulations

Tags: combinatorics

If there are 6 candidates and each is allotted one vote, but cannot vote for him or herself, what is the likelihood of each candidate taking a majority vote? A multi-way tie?

If given a specified order in which votes are cast, and votes are revealed immediately, which voting position offers the most benefit? Which offers the least?

Can this be generalized for n candidates?

Comment: Is a "majority vote" $4$ or more, or simply more than each other individual?  As for order, what are individuals' objectives in voting?

Comment: A majority vote would be more votes than any other candidate, so if the results were 2, 1, 1 and 1, the candidate with 2 votes would achieve a majority. A draw would be the case in which each candidate receives 1 vote, and a tie would be considered 2 or more candidates that have more than at least one other candidate but have equal amounts of votes themselves.

As for objectives, I should have been more clear in my initial question. By the most benefit I mean most likelihood of achieving a majority vote for the candidate's self.

Comment: How do the candidates vote? You mention likelihood - do they vote uniformly at random? Or do they vote strategically and if they cannot win themselves, vote at random?